# Firefox's "Tracking Protection" vs the "Disconnect" add-on

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

How does enabling Tracking Protection in Firefox compare to installing the [Disconnect](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disconnect/) add-on? I'm enabling Tracking Protection through `about:config` by setting `privacy.trackingprotection.enabled` to `true`, so Tracking Protection is always enabled, not just in Private Browsing as is the default. The [Firefox documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tracking-protection-pbm) suggests the "Tracking Protection feature uses a list provided by Disconnect to identify and block trackers". Does this mean the two are functionally equivalent?

Comment: Websites do not have to honor your tracking preference.  The header in this information is not honored.  Disconnect gives you the ability to block their individual cookies I would image, based on my limited researched, due to the mozilla add-on website not working in my current location.

Comment: I see, so Tracking Protection is basically passive, while Disconnect actively blocks cookies?

Comment: Tracking Protection, will block tracking cookies, when the website actually honors that header.

Comment: @Ramhound: That's incorrect. [Firefox's tracking protection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Privacy/Tracking_Protection) is a different feature than "do not track" header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both Disconnect and Firefox's tracking protection use identical list the functionality is equivalent. The Disconnect addon has some extra features such as "visualizing" connections on pages and whitelisting websites.
[Disconnect's "basic tracking list"](https://s3.amazonaws.com/lists.disconnect.me/simple_tracking.txt) is available online, but Firefox doesn't seem to allow inspecting its block lists (options > privacy > tracking > change block list) and hence there's no easy way to confirm if the exact same domains are used.

**UPDATE**: The addon seems to store the blocked domains in the `services.json` file (version 5.19.3) in `\data\`. You can download the .xpi file from [the Mozilla addons page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disconnect/) ("save link as") and open with 7-Zip.